# load policy.json file in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have my EKS specific user configuration in a json file that I want to load into terraform to apply it.

I use the data_source **aws_iam_policy_document**

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_document" "ops_manager" {                                                                                                       
policy = file("templates/eks_user_policy.json")         
    }
```

Unfortunately when i run **terraform plan** i got this:

> The provider provider.aws does not support resource type
> "aws_iam_policy_document".

terraform version: v0.14.9

Comment: How did it go. Is it still unclear why you have the error?

Answer (score 5):

[aws_iam_policy_document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) is a **data source**, not a `resource`.

Probably you want [aws_iam_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy):

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ops_manager" {                                                                                                       
    policy = file("templates/eks_user_policy.json")         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the JSON file there was a comment "//".
By deleting the comment the problem was solved.
maybe it help someone .

Comment: Nope, that simply is not the answer and cannot cause the error you received. What Marcin wrote is the correct solution to your problem.